# Flutter run error | Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart

Tried running flutter run post null safety migration, it's throwing below error

**[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value**

Below are the code snippet which is throwing above error.

```
AppStrings appText = await DatabaseUtils.getAppText(local!);



Data initialData = await initializeData(appDocumentDir.path, deviceId!);
```

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: try to remove `!` sign and set default value when its null

Comment: remove the `!` sign and set default value like this when its null 
`AppStrings appText = await DatabaseUtils.getAppText(local??defaultvalue);`

Comment: Even after adding above code, we are facing below error:-

 Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

 AppStrings appText = await DatabaseUtils.getAppText(local??defaultvalue!);

Comment: You need to write some value instead of defaultValue

Comment: Tried with below code 

  AppStrings? appText = await DatabaseUtils.getAppText(local ?? "uk");

it is throwing below error again:-

Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'